Features don't appear after connecting database in ArcGIS Pro
I have two different ArcGIS Pro projects (we'll call them Urban_2024 and WashingtonPlots) in the same located in the same directory. Because WashingtonPlots is newer but uses a lot of the same data that's already in Urban_2024's directory, I added a directory connection from WashingtonPlots to Urban_2024. The connection went great... except that none of the same features are there! Here is a screenshot from the WashingtonPlots project:

It appears to be functioning correctly. But looking at the same database from the Urban_2024 project:

...shows a completely different list of features.
What is happening here?
I'm pretty new to ArcGIS Pro.

Why are you connecting to a database to access a file geodatabase? Access it by a folder connection to the containing folder and see if the problem persists. File geodatabases are not databases.

@MichaelStimson ArcGIS Pro allows listing FGDBs in the Catalog under the Databases entry. The APRX default FGDB will always be listed under Databases. You can also see them under Folder connections as you note.  There's no difference in functionality, apart from being able to add multiple FGDBs from different folders to the Database entry without having to add their individual folders  to the Folder connections entry.

@user72959 have you right-clicked on each file gdb and selected Refresh?
